# pull random string from array, only once

Tags: android, arrays, string, random

I have a program that uses Random to generate a random number to select a string from an array. What I want to do is avoid the same string from being selected twice! I also want to store the entire list of pulled random strings and be able to clear them when needed.

My random string is displayed in a textView.

Comment: Can you provide code that you have tried, what happened when you ran it?

Comment: shuffle your list (Collections.shuffle) (or a copy of the list), then take items in order from the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
//use set to avoid Duplicatess....

Set<String> objSet = new HashSet<String>();
boolean one= objSet .add("hello");
System.out.println(one);             // Prints "true"
boolean two= objSet .add("hello");
System.out.println(two);           // Prints "false"

// if you want to remove Specific String after add then you have to use HashMap
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be to transform you array into a List, and create another list to store the pulled strings. So when you pull a random string, remove it from the original list and add it to the pulled strings list.

Something like

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(stringsArray);
List<String> usedStrings = new ArrayList<>();

String s = strings.remove(index);
doSomethingWithString(s);
usedStrings.add(s);
```

This way you won't be using the same string twice, and you can keep track on the used strings

Answer (score 0):

put the random string in an ArrayList.Before that check if doesnot contain any already. using !contains(randomstr) method else find other random